# In the figure below, M, N, and E are the mid-points of BC, MC, and AC respectively. If the length of BE is 42cm, find the length of GH in cm.

Tags: geometry

[image]

I've been trying to improve on Geometry but I honestly don't know how to approach this. I'm guessing the ratio of GH and HE and GE and BE has something to do with the ratio of MC and AC but I feel like I have insufficient information to work with. Help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $G$ is the centroid of the triangle $ABC$. Therefore $BG:GE=2:1$. Also, we can apply [Menelaus's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) to the suitable triangle and the line, to relate the ratios of lengthes. Can you find which triangle and line you can apply?